# 3D: Javascript API to develop an immersive 3D app for Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, 3d

Anyone knows any 3D API in Javascript to develop 3D apps in Facebook, comparable to this one: 
http://altadyn.com/developers-api/ ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) is a pretty sweet WebGL library.

Check out the examples here: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/